# How to change validation behavior on blur event of lightning-input component

Tags: validation, lightning-web-components

I set validation on lightning-input component as pattern and required attributes.
These validation works fine. But when blur event occurs on lightning-input, validation process is executed automatically.

I want to validate only at submitting form data via REST API.

How can I achieve this?

Sample template is simple as below.

```
<template>
    <div class="app slds-p-around_x-large">
        <lightning-input name="abc" label="abc" pattern="abc" required></lightning-input>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don`t have access to lightning-* component internals the only way i could imagine would be to bind the respective constraints to tracked properties which are not set on initial load. When submitting your data you set them to the values you like and call the reportValidity Method on the lightning-input.

Otherwise you have to roll your own form with native inputs